# How to set Timeout for downloading file in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to set a timeout for getting complete response from requested URL, for example `URL url = new URL("http://www.amrood.com");`

I create connection and I want to set the timeout for loading that page, if it is taking more then given time I want to get the timeout error.

The URL maybe a downloading I want the same logic, with in a time the file should download else I want the timeout error.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.amrood.com");
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        huc.setConnectTimeout(0); //for unlimited
```

else

```
huc.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000); //whatever time you want to put
```

Or you can try with Jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amrood.com").timeout(0).get();
```

Comment: String url = "https://irctc.co.in";
  final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,1000);
  URL obj = new URL(url);
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

  con.setConnectTimeout(100); 
  con.setReadTimeout(100);
  
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
  HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  System.out.println(response.toString());

Comment: First of all time in setConnectTimeout & setReadTimeout is in milliseconds, so 100 is too less to get the response.

Comment: Tried this and it is giving me complete response... String url1 = "http://irctc.co.in/";
     URL obj = new URL(url1);
     URLConnection con = obj.openConnection();
     con.setConnectTimeout(0);
     con.setReadTimeout(0);
     InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input);

     String inputLine;
     String fullline = "";

     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  fullline = fullline.concat(inputLine);

     }
     System.out.println(fullline);

Comment: yes your rite "setConnectTimeout & setReadTimeout is in milliseconds, so 100 is too less to get the response" Even I am getting response an a that sort time.. thats what my code is error here.. i want the error there not response

Comment: try {

     String url = "http://irctc.co.in/";
     URL obj = new URL(url);
     URLConnection con = obj.openConnection();
     con.setConnectTimeout(100);
     con.setReadTimeout(100);
     InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input);

     String inputLine;
     String fullline = "";

     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  fullline = fullline.concat(inputLine);

     }
     System.out.println(fullline);

 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error to fetch the details");

 }

Comment: your  code is correct dude.. instead of "http://irctc.co.in" you change the URL like "
http://www.theaudiocritic.com/back_issues/The_Audio_Critic_26_r.pdf 
" and set the read time out as 10000(10 Seconds) its taking more time and giving the response, but i need more then 10 seconds means error

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by [URLConnection#setReadTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)

urlconn.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 sec

// ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HttpURLConnection` then you can specify timeout using [setConnectTimeout](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) & [setReadTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)

```
con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout); 
con.setReadTimeout(socketTimeout);
```

Comment: Yes I trying both but am not getting error on that particular given time .. here am attached my code please check 

import java.io.IOException;